# Why can't we define the array size by a variable when we write C++ code in vs code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Why can't we define the array size by a variable when writing C++ in vs code?

l have typed the same code shown below in Dev C++, and such declaration is supported in Dev C++.

```
struct student_
{
    char name[11];
    char no[11];
    int grade;
};
struct student_ stu[n]; // not supported in vs code, but supported in Dev C++
```

I expect such declaration to be true, but the actual result is error.

Comment: Because the C++ Standard says so.

Comment: Because [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are not part of the C++ language. Some compiler add it as a non-portable extension to the language, but you really should not use such extensions. Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead if you have an "array" whose size needs to be set at run-time.

Comment: A conforming compiler is allowed to provide this extension, but it is required to issue a diagnostic if you use it. You probably got a warning in Dev C++ about a non-standard extension.

Comment: At least this person is asking.

Answer (score 4):

[Variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are not and have never been a part of standard C++. Thus, the size of a statically allocated array must be known at compile time. Some compilers support this functionality as a compiler extension (GCC does for instance), but it is not something portable. Use `std::vector` as a replacement.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays in C++ are static, and that's why their size needs to be known druing compile time so appropriate space can be allocated. You can initialize the size with a variable, but again that variable must have known constant value at compile time. For that you can use `constexpr` keyword.

In order for your example to work, `n` must be declared like this:

```
constexpr size_t n = 5;
```

When you directly write a number into the size initializer, that value is naturally known at compile time and thus valid as well.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you need to select g++ compiler
step 1: go to MinGw -> bin -> g++ -> press shift + right mouse button
step 2: open visual studio -> go to view -> Command pallete -> search for C++ (UI)
-> go to compiler path -> paste the g++ path and then scroll down and select IntelliSense mode select -> g++x64
All done!! Happy Coding

Comment: The answer is only true for some cases, what if you do not want to use the g++ compiler, what if you use clang++ or mscv++ instead. 
The reason this works in one compiler and not in another makes this answer symptom treatment and not a solution

Comment: Worked for me, esp since I only want to use g++ compiler.